# YouTube Data API V3 for Android issue

Tags: java, android, youtube

I try to make a simple Youtube tool which get info of a channel. I followed all steps on the document (create key on google cloud, libs from google-api-java-client, etc).

Here is my code snippet:

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
        new AndroidJsonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
public void initialize(HttpRequest request)
        throws IOException {
}
        }).setApplicationName(getPackageName()).build();
Util.log(this, "Init ok");

YouTube.Channels.List list = youtube.channels().list(
        "snippet");
list.setKey(<my_key>);//api key removed for privacy
list.setForUsername("xdadevelopers");
list.setMaxResults(5l);
ChannelListResponse res = list.execute();
```

I got a http status code of 403 - Access Not Configured. I also enable HTTP Transport debug logging. Here is logs I got from Eclipse console:

```
 D/HttpTransport(10317): -------------- REQUEST  --------------
 D/HttpTransport(10317): GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=xdadevelopers&key=<my_key as in java source code>&maxResults=5&part=snippet
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Accept-Encoding: gzip
 D/HttpTransport(10317): User-Agent: myapp.packagename Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.17.0-rc (gzip)
 D/HttpTransport(10317): curl -v --compressed -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: myapp.packagename Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.17.0-rc (gzip)' -- 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=xdadevelopers&key=<my_key>&maxResults=5&part=snippet'
 D/dalvikvm(10317): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 1% free 65212K/65540K, paused 36ms, total 37ms
 I/dalvikvm-heap(10317): Grow heap (frag case) to 92.083MB for 29748112-byte allocation
 D/dalvikvm(10317): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 94262K/94592K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
 D/dalvikvm(10317): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 1% free 94243K/94592K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
 I/dalvikvm-heap(10317): Grow heap (frag case) to 120.433MB for 29748112-byte allocation
 D/dalvikvm(10317): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 123294K/123644K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
 D/OpenGLRenderer(10317): Enabling debug mode 0
 D/HttpTransport(10317): -------------- RESPONSE --------------
 D/HttpTransport(10317): 403 Forbidden
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Content-Encoding: gzip
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Content-Length: 138
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2013 05:01:43 GMT
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Expires: Sat, 28 Dec 2013 05:01:43 GMT
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Server: GSE
 D/HttpTransport(10317): X-Android-Received-Millis: 1388206907784
 D/HttpTransport(10317): X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 403
 D/HttpTransport(10317): X-Android-Selected-Transport: http/1.1
 D/HttpTransport(10317): X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1388206907245
 D/HttpTransport(10317): X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 D/HttpTransport(10317): X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 D/HttpTransport(10317): X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 D/HttpTransport(10317): Total: 205 bytes
 D/HttpTransport(10317): {
 D/HttpTransport(10317):  "error": {
 D/HttpTransport(10317):   "errors": [
 D/HttpTransport(10317):    {
 D/HttpTransport(10317):     "domain": "usageLimits",
 D/HttpTransport(10317):     "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
 D/HttpTransport(10317):     "message": "Access Not Configured"
 D/HttpTransport(10317):    }
 D/HttpTransport(10317):   ],
 D/HttpTransport(10317):   "code": 403,
 D/HttpTransport(10317):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
 D/HttpTransport(10317):  }
 D/HttpTransport(10317): }
```

Notice: I don't authenticate since I just want to get public information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did all the steps as you and everything I could find, SHA-1 fingerprint, etc. and got the same error when using the Android app API key. What I did was create a new app on Google Cloud and use the Browser API key rather than the Android app key.

Comment: It works. However, it looks like a tricky way to use the API. Further, if you publish your app and someone can decode the app to obtain your API-key and they can steal your quota. Do you see any documentation about this?

Comment: There isn't any documentation that I can find on how to do it correctly for Android app. I'm guessing it doesn't work because how does the server know the SHA-1 fingerprint? There must be an extra step we're missing. The danger of someone stealing your key is the same as many other API's out there, there are ways to encrypt, that's a separate story.

Comment: If you find out how to make Android app key work, please let us all know.